# Runtime Library error. Не запускается приложение

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, сборка, runtime

При запуске приложения вылетает ошибка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написал на C++ и Qt 5.9.1 приложение. Писал в QtCreator, компилируется с помощью MinGW 5.3.0 32bit, ОС Windows 7 64. Собрал в релиз, прогнал Windeploy, добавил нужные библиотеки согласно [Qt for Windows - Deployment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html). [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тестировал на 5 компах и 3 виртуалках. На моём компе запускается. На компе с практически чистой win7 64 тоже работает. На виртуалках с чистыми win7 64 и win10 64 не работает, ещё на трёх реальных компах с win7 и win10 тоже не запускается. Ещё была виртуалка, только не я её делал, на win10 64, там прога работала.

Пробовал ставить все возможные .Net и Visual C++ библиотеки - не помогает. Пробовал пересобирать проект - не помогло. Написал тестовое приложение, тоже в QtCreator - оно работает.

Pro файл проекта -

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2018-02-06T14:45:04
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui
QT       += axcontainer
QT       += concurrent

LIBS += -lmpr
LIBS += -lwbemuuid

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = second_Net_Please
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    ... (мои файлы)

HEADERS += \
    ... (мои файлы)
```

Comment: что значит "не запускается"?

Comment: @BeardedBeaver добавил в вопрос

Comment: Могу предположить, что проблема в неопределенном поведении, а не в том, что не хватает каких-то библиотек. Проверьте неинициализированные переменные, прогоните код статическим анализатором.

Comment: @BeardedBeaver CppCheck ничего важного не нашёл

Comment: Вижу по списку файлов, что используется OpenGL. Попробуйте видео драйвера обновить на проблемных машинах.

Comment: "Пробовал ставить все возможные .Net и Visual C++ библиотеки" - Зачем ставить все возможные? Поставьте те, которые используются, этого достаточно. Выясните, на чем именно падает (отладчиком или через логирование, если падает в вашем коде).

Comment: @alexolut Я opengl не использовал, только Qt компоненты, но Windeploy сам добавляет её, так что я не стал удалять

Comment: Отлаживать пробовали¿ и нет, такая ошибка не возникает из за недостающих библиотек,

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight нашёл ошибку, забыл try catch в одном месте. Логированием нашёл, так что можете написать ответ - отмечу. Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Механизм появления такой ошибки

Сообщение "*This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way*" выводится, когда:

- в приложении С++ возникло необработанное исключение
- версия стандартной библиотеки Visual C++ - 2010 или ниже
- приложение собрано с использованием отладочной версии стандартной библиотеки

Если версия стандартной библиотеки Visual C++ - 2012 или более новая, вместо этого будет выведено другое сообщение, чуть более осмысленное ("*abort() has been called*" - см. ниже) и позволяющее по нажатию кнопки **Retry** активировать just-in-time отладчик, если он установлен в системе.

Если приложение собрано с использованием релизной версии стандартной библиотеки, вместо этого выведется сообщение с предложением отправить отчет в Microsoft, а также в системный журнал будет занесено событие Application Error. Если установлен just-in-time отладчик, он, скорее всего, активируется автоматически и предложит выполнить отладку.

---

Может показаться странным, почему выводится такое малоинформативное сообщение. Это связано с принятым в С++ механизмом обработки исключений. Если исключение не обработано ни одним обработчиком в пользовательском коде, будет вызван специальный аварийный обработчик. Он имеет такой прототип:

```
void terminate(void);
```

Как видно, в него не передается вообще никаких параметров об ошибке, поэтому вывести информативное сообщение невозможно. Реализация этого обработчика по умолчанию просто вызывает функцию [abort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k089yyh0(v=vs.110).aspx). Эта функция и выводит сообщение об ошибке (в отладочном режиме), вызывает сигнал SIGABRT (который позволяет отладчику включится в работу), а затем завершает работу приложения. Этот обработчик можно переопределить вызовом `set_terminate`, но обычно толку от этого нет.

Подробнее: [Unhandled C++ Exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac9f67ah.aspx)

---

**Примечание.** Эта ошибка почти никогда не связана с отсутствием каких-то библиотек. При отсутствии библиотек, слинкованных через LIB-файл, обычно выводится что-то вроде "*Не удалось запустить приложение, потому что оно некорректно настроено*".

## Как отладить такую ошибку

Обычно ответ прост - обрабатывать все исключения и выводить на экран и/или в лог подробную информацию об ошибке (можно также логировать и весь ход работы программы, чтобы было проще определить, на каком этапе возникла проблема). В случае данного вопроса, этого было достаточно.

Однако, иногда могут возникнуть более сложные ситуации. Что, если программа падает с загадочной ошибкой глубоко внутри функции сторонней библиотеки, от которой нет исходников? Тогда понадобится использовать отладчик - стандартный из студии или WinDBG. Для получения максимального эффекта от отладчика нужно:

- Подложить файлы символов (*.pdb) ко всем модулям, для которых они есть
- Настроить отладчик на использование серверов символов Microsoft (там лежат символы от стандартной библиотеки и библиотек ОС)
- Включить автоматическую остановку на исключениях

Это позволит извлечь какую-то информацию из кода ошибки, места ее возникновения и стека вызовов в этот момент.

**Ссылки:**

[Debugging Native Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k70yt3e2.aspx)

[Документация WinDBG](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/)

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в том, что у меня не ловился один exception, который и вызывал ошибку. Не знал, что при такой ошибке может Runtime error выскакивать, поэтому не сразу догадался. При запуске программы идёт работа с реестром, там и был exception