# Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime error

Tags: c++, qt, runtime

Возникает периодически ошибка Runtime error:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Когда в отладочном режиме запускаю, доходит до строчки ui->setupUi(this);

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "login.h"
#include "ksp_ecology_hold.h"
#include "ksp_ecology_water.h"
#include "dialoginformation.h"
#include <QQmlContext>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this); // до этой строчки доходит, потом обращается к файлу  ui_mainwindow.h
...
}
....
```

ui_mainwindow.h:

```
...
    void setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
    {
        if (MainWindow->objectName().isEmpty())
            MainWindow->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("MainWindow"));
...
```

и на этой строчки  `MainWindow->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("MainWindow"));`
Вылетает с ошибкой Runtime error. В чём может быть дело? Это не из-за того что когда я вызываю окошко MainWindow в файле login.cpp:

```
...
            ui->label_status->setText("username and password is correct");
            connClose();
            this->hide();
            mainwindow = new MainWindow(this);
            mainwindow->showMaximized();
...
```

передаю `QWidget *parent`, а в MainWindow :`QMainWindow(parent)`?

Comment: Если строчка вылета известна, смотрите значения переменных, которые в ней используются. Например, валидность указателя `MainWindow`.

Comment: @alexolut Я не совсем понимаю, что значит валидность указателя  MainWindow ? Можно пояснить . qDebug()<<this; выводит MainWindow(0x3acad1a0)

Comment: Не очень понял, вылет в момент создания объекта класса `MainWindow` при старте программы, или дальше в процессе работы создается окно?

Comment: @Bearded Beaver Собирается проект , выводиться окошко логина и пароля, а потом после правильного ввода логина и пароля , в момент когда должно открыться окно MainWindow  , вылетает с ошибкой  Runtime error

Comment: я по этим урокам делал окна login и MainWindow : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZ9Mejld2lI&list=PLS1QulWo1RIZjrD_OLju84cUaUlLRe5jQ&index=14

Comment: Так а вы смотрели стек вызовов/значения переменных, или нет? Кроме того, подозрительно, что ошибка visual c++, а проект mingw.

Comment: @VTT Я 3 месяца назад стал изучать C++ так , что прошу прощение за мою глупость. Но как посмотреть стек вызовов? И о каких переменных идёт речь ? Передается только this в окно MainWindow

Comment: @VTT Ничего удивительного, многое в стандартной библиотеке  MinGW - просто обертка от аналогичных функций Microsoft CRT (причем безнадежно устаревшей версии). Функция abort, которая выводит это сообщение, видимо тоже входит сюда.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/782030/runtime-library-error-Не-запускается-приложение

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Может такая ошибка возникать когда что то не правильно с логикой, деление на ноль или банально не правильно выделяю память для массивов? Потому что эта проблема уходит, когда иногда видишь ошибки и исправляешь их. В приложении С++ возникло необработанное исключение и это один из ключевых ответов на мой вопрос я думаю.

Comment: При подобных ошибках может быть разное сообщение, в зависимости от ситуации. Выход за границы массива или деление на ноль обычно дает исключение уровня ОС (его нельзя перехватить с помощью catch), но сообщение об ошибке в итоге может быть такое же. Чтобы проще это было отлаживать, рекомендуется настроить отладчик в вашей IDE на автоматическую остановку на исключениях, тогда вместо этого сообщения вы можете получить что-то более информативное.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Есть инструкция для IDE Qt Creator, как настроить  автоматическую остановку на исключениях?

Comment: Посмотрите вот здесь http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debug-mode.html и здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735413/how-can-i-make-qtcreator-break-on-exceptions